# Can someone explain Clojure's unquote-splice in simple terms?

Tags: clojure

I am banging my head against the wall trying to understand some Clojure macros which use unquote-splice, and I can't seem to find out any clear expanation of whay they are needed. Can anyone explain it to me in dummy terms?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm no expert on Clojure, but since it's basically a Lisp, things should be like that unquote-splice is unquote which merges the list to the position where it's used. Difference looks like this:

```
`(1 2 ~(list 3 4))   =>  (1 2 (3 4))
`(1 2 ~@(list 3 4))  =>  (1 2 3 4)

`  == syntax-quote
~  == unquote
~@ == unquote-splice
```

Comment: Ah, so unquote-splice just flattens a list?

Comment: @Zubair: yep. Also note, that in CLojure `~` (tilde) is used instead of `,` (comma).

Comment: @ffriend: \`(As someone who likes ,(nth (random 2) '(many some)) of the changes in Closure I'm surprised by their using `~` (tilde) over the traditional `,` (comma) — any idea why it was changed?)

Comment: @Baldur: there may be 2 possible reasons. First, comma may be considered as not descriptive and confusing - quote does exactly the same thing it does in natural language - quotes symbol (marks denotation, in linguistic terms), but comma does very different thing from what it means in the language. So it makes sense to change it to something else. Second, more weighty reason, is that for readability purposes Clojure allows using commas instead of whitespaces where it makes sense and thus cannot be used as a shortcut for `eval`.